# Write in file .txt in java

Tags: java, file, mod-rewrite

I want write in file .txt and i try this:

`save_arq.print("%s;%d:%f;", entry.getValue(), entry.getKey(), result);`

I initialize the file this modo:

```
Scanner file_tf_idf = new Scanner(System.in);
FileWriter arq = new FileWriter("C:\\tf_idf.txt");
PrintWriter save_arq = new PrintWriter(arq);
```

But i have error in save_arq.print.

My complete code:

```
public class tfidfWeights {

public Map<String, Integer> tfidf(Map<String, Integer> tf_C) throws IOException{

        Scanner file_tf_idf = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileWriter arq = new FileWriter("C:\\tf_idf.txt");
        PrintWriter save_arq = new PrintWriter(arq);          

        Map<String, Integer> idf = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


        //Set<Integer> doc_id = new HashSet<Integer>(tf_C.keySet());
        Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = tf_C.entrySet();
        Iterator it = set.iterator();

        Integer N_total = tf_C.size();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            //iterar o map
            Entry<String, Integer> entry = (Entry)it.next();

            double result = 0;
            result = Math.log10(N_total/entry.getValue());
            save_arq.print("%s;%d:%f;", entry.getValue(), entry.getKey(), result);
            System.out.print(result);
        }
        save_arq.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post the full stack trace/a [MCVE]

Comment: There is no `print()` method that accepts those arguments. Did you mean to use `printf()`?

Comment: Also that is not the stacktrace. To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

Comment: Please fix your question so that it is helpful to future visitors -- please post the actual stacktrace. Also are you trying to run non-compilable code? If so, never do that -- get the errors from the compiler and fix those first before trying to run.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `print` method in the [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) class that accepts those arguments. I'm assuming you wanted to use the [`printf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method, which accepts:

```
printf(String format, Object... args)
```

So your code would be:

```
save_arq.printf("%s;%d:%f;", entry.getValue(), entry.getKey(), result);
```